# WPF: Data Grid not horizontally scrollable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have following DataGrid:

```
<Grid Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="400"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

...

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
                <DataGrid  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ExcelFileDataView, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

...

</Grid>
```

But when I make the app window smaller the whole window becomes horizontally scrollable instead of the `DataGrid`.
What do I need to do to make only the `DataGrid` horizontally scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `DataGrid` into a `ScrollViewer`. It has scrollbars on its own, so move `...ScrollBarVisibility` attributes to the `DataGrid` and everything will be fine.

Comment: I did but same result: <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ExcelFileDataView, Mode=TwoWay}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>

Comment: Please post more of your xaml (the whole grid, which contains the `DataGrid`). I suspect the 7 columns to receive a specific width from other controls. Post the `ColumnDefinitions` as well.